# Google-service Plugin

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am trying to work with Firebase for the first time. I got a project setup in firebase.

Project - build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
          }
    }
}
```

App - build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0'
}
```

But still, while syncing Gradle, I get this Error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2.

What am I missing, what is wrong here.

Comment: Try adding `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of the file, after the `dependencies {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the bottom of the App build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete a line 
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
because "com.android.application" package already has same package.
So add

apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
instead of

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'